# Mysql assign a single column value to a declared value using Select case

Tags: mysql

I am stucked with following issue, 
I ve delcared a varibale (DOUBLE) in a stored procedure, and i need to assign a value (item price) from a table (item) to this declared variable. however, i need to get this value from a select query which uses case inside, the item price could be in 2 columns based on a logic i have to find the correct item price. Please help me solve this as when i execute it gives me a error,

Here how is layered,

```
 DECLARE  no_more_users INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE user_id INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cart_id INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cart_item_id INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE  user_gift_id INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE itemPrice DOUBLE DEFAULT 0.0;
    SELECT  
        CASE
            WHEN sale_price=0 OR sale_price IS NULL THEN (price - ( price * discount ))
            ELSE sale_price
        END  
        INTO itemPrice
    FROM item  WHERE item_id = p_item_id ;   

    DECLARE  checked_in_users CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT DISTINCT ul.user_id
            FROM user_location ul 
            LEFT JOIN location_section ls ON ul.location_section_id = ls.location_section_id
            INNER JOIN user u ON ul.user_id = u.user_id
            INNER JOIN user_profile up ON u.user_id = up.user_id
            INNER JOIN location_event le ON ul.location_event_id = le.location_event_id                 
            WHERE ul.location_id = p_location_id AND ul.location_event_id = p_event_id 
            AND ul.checked_out_on IS NULL AND (ul.checked_in_on BETWEEN le.start_time AND le.end_time )
            AND u.status = 1 ;

    DECLARE  CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
    SET  no_more_users = 1;
    OPEN  checked_in_users;
        FETCH  checked_in_users INTO user_id;
        read_loop: LOOP
```

some more code...

please note, sale_price, price, and discount are coulmns of item table, The logic is if sale_price is null or value is 0, then i actual sale price should be obtained from price coulmn. Finally what i need is asign corect item price in to previously declared varibale.
Any help will be highly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two foms to the CASE statement, one with expressions and one with values. You are mixing them up.

with values:

```
CASE variable
WHEN value_1 THEN foo
WHEN value_2 THEN bar
END
```

with expressions:

```
CASE
WHEN expression_1 THEN foo
WHEN expression_2 THEN bar
END
```

Try

```
CASE
WHEN sale_price=0 OR sale_price IS NULL THEN (price - ( price * discount ))
ELSE sale_price
END
```

Also, you do not need the "AS correct_price" when you are using an INTO

Comment: Thanks, problem iam having is assign this sale price to delcared varivale. i did following, but it didnt work. `SELECT  CASE
            WHEN sale_price=0 OR sale_price IS NULL THEN (price - ( price * discount ))
            ELSE sale_price
            END INTO itemPrice 
        FROM item  WHERE item_id = p_item_id ;` would you be able to provide me correct syntax in this regard?

Comment: i tried this, `SELECT  
            CASE
                WHEN sale_price=0 OR sale_price IS NULL THEN (price - ( price * discount ))
                ELSE sale_price
            END  
            INTO itemPrice
        FROM item  WHERE item_id = p_item_id ; ` this statemnt throws an error in next statment, when i commented out this, it works.

Comment: i ve modified my question to get better understand about the problem

Comment: You get an error for the next statement because you must put all your DECLARE statements before your code statements.

Comment: Thanks fisharebest, You saved my day. It worked when i moved all declarations before select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your select query has some problems.

The version of CASE you are are using - ie CASE var WHEN val1 THEN - doesn't work when trying to match a NILL, because in SQL null is not equal to null.

Also, you can't combine values with conditions as you hAve.

Instead, use the version if CASS that simply conditions. There are other suntactic problems. Converting your broken query then gives:

```
SELECT
   CASE 
      WHEN ifnull(sale_price, 0) = 0 THEN price - (price * discount)
      ELSE sale_price 
   END
INTO itemPrice 
FROM item
WHERE item_id = p_item_id;
```

Note: if your table has s column called `itemPrice`, you must choose another name from your variable. Mysql gets confused :/

Comment: I ve updated my question to getter idea, this gives an error at declare CURSOR, but if i commented out assign item price to declared itemPrice variable, it works fine.